# Too many white space in bottom of the pages

Tags: geometry, book-design

I used this code for my thesis

```
\documentclass [12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[left=35mm,top=26mm,right=26mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
```

It shows acceptable white space in bottom of the page at the PDF viewer but when I

print it out it looks too large!

any idea

Comment: Perhaps the PDF viewer thinks your paper size is different than your actual paper size.  The other possibility I've seen happen is that, in Windows, the print driver can be told to "shrink to fit" which will screw up margins, too.  The proper setting is "print actual size".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i used SumatraPDF . how can i adjust that?

Comment: I am only familiar with the Adobe reader, so sorry.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i can change it to Adobe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The page size of the document is `letterpaper`, the default for the standard classes. If you want to generate a page layout for A4 paper, it must be explicitly set:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[left=35mm,top=26mm,right=26mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
```

or

```
\documentclass [12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,top=26mm,right=26mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
```

**Remarks:**

- The standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) contain:

  ```
  \ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,...}
  ```

  Therefore the default page layout is assigned for this paper size.
- A different matter is the media size of the document whicht the output driver generates. Unfortunately neither the LaTeX kernel nor the standard classes tell the paper size to the output driver. Without information the output driver has to use its default.

  However there are packages such as `geometry`, `hyperref`, drivers for `graphics`/`color` that provide the service telling the output driver the media size. Internally it is done by a `\special` or by setting special registers `\pdfpagewidth`, `\pdfpageheight`.
- In this case, the class has executed the default option `letterpaper`, package `geometry` has told this paper size to the output driver program to generate a document with this paper size. But the result was finally printed on A4 paper with a smaller width and larger height.
  Therefore setting the right option is the right answer.

Comment: Also, I read somewhere that it is recommended to pass `a4paper` as a class option, like language specifications. So the first is probably preferable.

Comment: @cfr: See the edited answer with the remarks. `geometry` has used `letterpaper` just because the class has set this paper size. The default for the standard classes *cannot* be configured, it is *always* `letterpaper`.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. But what then is the point of being able to configure the size via `tlmgr`? What does that setting affect?

Comment: @cfr: The default for the engines is set and used for lazy documents that do not tell the output driver the page size.

Answer (score 2):

If you have zeniko's version of SumatraPDF (you can find it on [his site](http://www.zeniko.ch/#SumatraPDF), typing Ctrl+D twice will show the dimension of the page and the list of the fonts used in the document. I don't think it's a problem with the pdf viewer (it reads the page format in the document) but most probably your printer is configured for a format that's different from your .pdf.

As you didn't specify any paper format in you preamble, it probably produces a letter paper format (8.5in × 11 in, or 215.9 mm × 279.4 mm), so if your printer settings are for a4paper (8.27 in × 11.69 in or 210 mm × 297 mm), your printed page will look weird.

Comment: Sorry for my duplicate answer. I wrote it rather leisurely, and posted it without checking an answer was posted meanwhile.

Comment: Alas, site is down ITM.